# React.js Hiding a button in a higher component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `Sidebar` component which is present in all my pages.
This `Sidebar` has a "Create New Post" button.
When clicked, the button redirects to the `NewDiary` component.

```
<HashRouter>
    <div className='app'>
      <div id='wrapper'>
        <div id='content' className='mobileUI-main-content'>
          <div id='content-inner'>
            <Match exactly pattern='/entry/new' component={NewDiary} />
            <Match exactly pattern='/entry/:id' component={DiaryDetails} />
            <Match exactly pattern='/' component={LandingPage} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <Sidebar />
      </div>
    </div>
  </HashRouter>
```

How can I make it so that the `Sidebar` knows that I've opened `NewDiary` and have it hide the button?
I am not using Redux and I'd like to avoid it too, as my app is incredibly small.

Comment: what is the route u r using for `NewPost` component ?

Comment: you need to send a prop to your sidebar like showPostNewButton="pattern!=entry/new" (dummy code, just to get the idea)

Comment: Sure I could send a prop but how would it access the pattern which was entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the current path from your props, and make condition using your path or router from your NewDiary page.

```
   const currentPath = this.props.location.pathname
   return (
     <div>
      {if currentPath === '/entry/new' ?<YourButtonComponent /> : null}
     </div>
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

In the SideBar `Component` check what the current route is.

```
const currentPath = this.props.location.pathname
```

If it is the one with NewDiary, do not render the button. You can pass this from your children component (which are rendered by the `Router`) to the `SideBar` component.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answers for pointing me in the right direction.

Another stumbling block was that `this.props.location` was undefined.
I searched around a bit and found out that I had to include the `Sidebar` component in a `Match` to have those props be sent down to him.

So what I did was add `<Match pattern='' component={Sidebar} />`

Such that every path renders the Sidebar and send down the `pathname` to it.